# How do I get multiple checkbox values and send the values via ajax in jquery?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I have 4 checkboxes. All in form of;

```
input type="checkbox" name="Group[]" id="Group" value="uniquevalue"
```

I have 3 of 4 of them checked. How can I send the values that are checked in the form

`"a = chkedvalue1 &b = chkedvalue2 &c = chkedvalue3"`?

I'm using jquery 1.4.2

Thank you! Spent a whole day with this issue to no avail.

Comment: Don't. Really. Have the server side process expect `Group[]=chkedvalue1&Group[]=chkedvalue2&Group[]=chkedvalue3` (which is how the form data will be encoded using a normal forum submission (this way you can [build on things that work](http://icant.co.uk/articles/pragmatic-progressive-enhancement/#build))) and then just use jQuery's `serialize()`

Answer (score 4):

First, remove that `id` attribute, it needs to be unique.  Then to get the array of values you can just [`.serialize()`](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/) the `<form>` like this:

```
var data = $("form").serialize();
```

Note this will produce `Group[]=...`, remove the `[]` from the `name` attributes if you just want `Group=` for each.

...or if you want the array of values, use [`.map()`](http://api.jquery.com/map/), like this:

```
var arr = $("input[name='Group[]']:checked").map(function() { 
            return this.value; 
          }).get();
```

Comment: Thank you. This was the answer.

Answer (score 3):

```
<?php
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
mysql_select_db("test",$con);
$ID = $_GET['id'];
$sql = "select city_name from city where id='$id'";
$fetch = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query($sql));
$result = explode(",",$fetch['city_name']);
?>
<html>
<body>
<form method="post" >
<input type="checkbox" name="city[]" value="Faridabad" <?php for($i=0;$i<4;$i++) if($result[$i]=='Faridabad')echo 'checked'; ?> />Faridabad
<input type="checkbox" name="city[]" value="Gurgaon" <?php for($i=0;$i<4;$i++) `if($result[$i]=='Gurgaon') echo 'checked';?>/>Gurgaon`
<input type="checkbox" name="city[]" value="Noida"<?php for($i=0;$i<4;$i++) if($result[$i]=='Noida') echo 'checked'; ?>/>Noida
<input type="checkbox" name="city[]" value="Gaziabad" <?php for($i=0;$i<4;$i++) if($result[$i]=='Gaziabad') echo 'checked'; ?>/>Gaziabad
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for posting an answer! While a code snippet could answer the question it's still great to add some addition information around, like explain, etc ..

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you [serialize](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/) the form.

Comment: Thank you. That's the function I was looking for.